# Use YARP in kubernetes as a service plus ingress

Tags: kubernetes, api-gateway, ms-yarp

Following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/implement-api-gateways-with-ocelot).

I'm wondering if it's okay or good practice to add a BFF/gateway(YARP) as a service in K8S with an Ingress in front? I have some custom code in my YARP such as JWT validation and REDIS token invalidation services which seem difficult to achieve with APIM or APIGateway from Azure.

Comment: It seems to me that it would be ok to do what you are suggesting. Especially considering that YARP has an article related to what you are asking. -> https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy/blob/main/docs/docfx/articles/kubernetes-ingress.md